# How do I show a role name instead of its id in an @Html.DropDownListFor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an unregister form and I must choose the User Role (Admin or User), but I don't know how to show in my drop-down list the name of the Role and not the id.

My Controller is:

```
public ActionResult Register()
{
    CDraguseniDBEntities dbContext = new CDraguseniDBEntities();
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = dbContext.Users.Select(c => new SelectListItem
    {              
        Value=c.RoleID,
        Text =c.RoleID.ToString()
    });
    ViewBag.RoleID = items;
    return View();
}
```

My View is:

```
@model ExamenBudescuMarius_2emeSes.Models.UserModel

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Register";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Register</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>UserModel</legend>


    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RoleID)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RoleID)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RoleID)
    </div>

    <div>
        <p>Role ID</p>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RoleID, ViewBag.RoleID as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "-Select a value-", new { @class = "dropDown" })
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Username)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
    </div>


    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

My Model is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using CompareAttribute = System.Web.Mvc.CompareAttribute;

namespace ExamenBudescuMarius_2emeSes.Models
{
public class UserModel
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 8)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Your Name is required")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Your name must be maximum 50 letters.")]
    [Remote("UsernameExists", "Account", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "User name already registered.")]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Your Last Name is required")]
    [StringLength(70, ErrorMessage = "Your name must be max 70 letters.")]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}", ErrorMessage = "Email doesn't look like a valid email address.")]
    [Remote("EmailExists", "Account", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "Email address already registered.")]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int RoleID { get; set; }

    public virtual Roles Roles { get; set; }

    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 8)]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

My database tables are:

```
CREATE TABLE Roles(
    RoleID int identity(1,1) Primary key not null,
    RoleName varchar(50) not null
);
create table Users(
    UserID int identity(1,1) primary key not null,
    Username varchar(100) not null,
    [Password] varchar(120) not null,
    FirstName varchar(120) not null,
    LastName varchar(120) not null,
    Email varchar(120) not null,
    RoleID int not null,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_RoleIDRoles] FOREIGN KEY ([RoleID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Roles]     ([RoleID])
);

create table Album(
    AlbumID int identity(1,1)  primary key not null,
    AlbumName varchar(120) not null
);
create table Images(
    ImageID int identity(1,1) primary key not null,
    ImageName varchar(120) not null,
    ImagePath nvarchar(100) not null,
    ImageDescription varchar(max) ,
    AlbumID int,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Images_Album] FOREIGN KEY ([AlbumID]) REFERENCES [dbo]. [Album] ([AlbumID])
);
```

Comment: When building "items" why do you query "Users" instead of "Roles"? You should query the last and then use Text=c.Name

Answer (score 1):

First, You should query the Roles collection of your dbContext to get a list of Roles. When you build the `items` collection, Get the `RoleName` and use that to set the Text property of SelectListItem.

```
var items = dbContext.Roles
                     .Select(c => new  SelectListItem
                                                     { 
                                                       Value = c.RoleID.ToString(),
                                                       Text = c.RoleName
                                                     });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'have managed to show in my drop-down list the name of the Role  and now after I submit the form I receive un error like :

> The ViewData item that has the key 'RoleID' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'.
>   Description : Une exception non gérée s'est produite au moment de l'exécution de la requête Web actuelle. Contrôlez la trace de la pile pour plus d'informations sur l'erreur et son origine dans le code.
>
> Détails de l'exception: System.InvalidOperationException: The ViewData item that has the key 'RoleID' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'.

Erreur source:

```
 Ligne 24 :         <div>
 Ligne 25 :             <p>Role ID</p>
 Ligne 26 :               @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RoleID,     ViewBag.RoleList as SelectList, "-Select a value-", new { @class = "dropDown" })
 Ligne 27 :         </div>
 Ligne 28 : 

Fichier source : d:\ephec\2015-2016\Web côté client\ExamenBudescuMarius- 2emeSes\ExamenBudescuMarius-2emeSes\Views\Account\Register.cshtml    Ligne : 26
```

Now my controller looks like :

```
   public ActionResult Register()
    {

        CDraguseniDBEntities dbContext = new CDraguseniDBEntities();
        UserModel um = new UserModel();

        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = new SelectList(dbContext.Roles, "RoleID", "RoleName", um.RoleID);
        ViewBag.RoleList = items;

 /* 
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = dbContext.Roles.Select(c => new    SelectListItem
        {

            Text=c.RoleName,

        });
        ViewBag.RoleID = items;*/
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Register(UserModel U)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (CDraguseniDBEntities dc = new CDraguseniDBEntities())
            {

                var count = dc.Users.Count(use => use.Username == U.Username);
                //you should check duplicate registration here 
               if(count==0)
               {
                   Users user = new Users();

                   user.RoleID = U.RoleID;
                   user.FirstName = U.FirstName;
                   user.LastName = U.LastName;
                   user.Email = U.Email;
                   user.Username = U.Username;
                   user.Password = U.Password;
                   dc.Users.Add(user);
                   dc.SaveChanges();
                   ModelState.Clear();
                   U = null;
                   ViewBag.Message = "Successfully Registration Done";

               }
               else
               {
                   ViewBag.Message = "User already exist";
               }
            }
        }
        return View(U);
    }
```